# How do I pass data from a dialog to a different dialog? Android studio

Tags: java, android, dialog

I have dialog1 which inside of it there is a button, when I click the button I want dialog2 to open up, dialog2 has an EditText and when I type something and submit dialog2 closes and the text will show up in dialog1.

I tried to do it with an interface but it only works when I pass data from a dialog to an activity, in this case I want to pass data from a dialog to another dialog.

Comment: What's the type of dialog you're opening? Could you share the relevant code? And I think you're opening the dialogs from an activity, correct?

Comment: You can intent. And pass data with putExtra. And when is click in dilaog1 button going to dialog2. Your data put intent. And get your data in dialog2

Comment: You dont need an interface. Uou can just store the data from the second in the first. Does your first dialog keep alive when you show the second?

Answer (score 0):

You can store data in a shared viewModel, using LiveData for example